# Lambda with explicit object parameter and std::invoke_result_t

Tags: c++, lambda, type-deduction, c++23, explicit-object-parameter

How do I get the return type of a lambda that has a deducing this signature using `std::invoke_result_t`.

```cpp
auto lambda = [](this auto& self, int x) -> int {
    return x;
};  
  
auto x = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(lambda), int>{}; //won't compile
```

Do I need to somehow specify the self argument inside the `std::invoke_result_t` ?

I've tried without "deducing this" and the above sample works.

Edit:
[compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:50,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:50,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:50,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:50,startLineNumber:6),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Aauto+lambda+%3D+%5B%5D(this+auto%26+self,+int+x)+-%3E+int+%7B%0A++++return+x%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++auto+x+%3D+std::invoke_result_t%3Cdecltype(lambda),+int%3E%7B%7D%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%232%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x64+msvc+v19.latest+(Editor+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.1%27,editorid:2,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x64+msvc+v19.latest+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: I'm playing around with meta-programming a bit. I've tried passing `std::invoke_result_t<decltype(lambda), decltype(lambda)&, int>{};`  and similar. 
It didn't work for me.

Comment: Your `std::invoke_result_t<decltype(lambda), decltype(lambda)&, int>{};` [seems to work](https://godbolt.org/z/KxdrjTYn4); EDIT but maybe because without `__cpp_explicit_this_parameter`

Comment: Your snippet works in MSVC latest (which has full support for C++23): https://godbolt.org/z/McGbGKzdY, but doesn't in any other compiler (i.e. GCC https://godbolt.org/z/3ox9roc14). I would say it is still an unsupported feature...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Your snippet works with a slight modification to the `this` parameter. It works without the reference marker

Comment: But passing by reference (I think) is an error. `this` must be passed either by value  (pointer copy) or as a forwarding reference. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp23-deducing-this/. Both work fine

Comment: That's it thank you guys :D. 
Yes this c++23 feature is currently only on msvc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your lambda, `this auto& self` actually takes an *lvalue* reference to `this`, but `std::invoke_result_t<decltype(lambda), int>` invokes the *rvalue* lambda.

Since the rvalue cannot be bound to the lvalue reference, `invoke_result` has no valid member `type`, just as `std::move(lambda)(0)` is ill-formed.

You should invoke the lambda with an lvalue, e.g.

```
auto x = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(lambda)&, int>{};
```

Or make the lambda accept a *forward reference* to `this`

```
auto lambda = [](this auto&& self, int x) -> int {
    return x;
};
```